# How to avoid sqlite Error in C# while updating selected row?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a form update a selected row in sqlite in win forms applications C#.
But there is still an error:

```
SQL logic error
near "ID": syntax error
```

My part of code:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Transport = "Update TransportMed set Imię = "+textBox2.Text+", Nazwisko = " +textBox3.Text+", PESEL ="+textBox3.Text+"where ID = " + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            ExcecuteQuery(Transport);
            LoadData();
        }
```

Comment: You need a space before the WHERE.

Comment: Still an error near ","

Comment: **Use parameters** or you will get syntax errors and injection risks left and right

Comment: Post the actual Command Text Transport so we can see the actaul query.  There may be extra characters in the DGV Cell that is causing an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jdweng has mentioned, you need a space before `where`:

```
string Transport = "Update TransportMed set Imię = " + textBox2.Text + ", Nazwisko = " + textBox3.Text + ", PESEL =" + textBox3.Text + " where ID = " + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Please be careful that the current method is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You have to use Sql parameters to avoid it. Read more here: [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14376473/7003797)

Comment: Still an error near ","

Comment: Can you print `Transport` in a message box or use Debug.WriteLine()? It will help you see where the SQL statement is ill formated: